# How can a Centre get server's hardware information by IPMI address?

Tags: ipmi, bmc

I find there is a way to [automated hardware information collection](https://www.noc-ps.com/automated-hardware-information-collection/).

but what's the principle ? why the Centre know a Server's IPMI address then it can get the Server's hardware information?

Is there any protocol of BMC to provide this function?

Answer (score 0):

Most BMC platforms offer SNMP as a management interface. It would likely change between vendors, but that would be the best unified way to capture the information across different vendors.